# Manually run a job from scheduler?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Suppose I have a job (for example, RUNTHIS) and I have its entry number (for example, 000123) scheduled to be ran every week on monday at 12 PM or something.

Let's say on a Wednesday, I want to run this job out of the blue.  Is there a command I can run to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By scheduler, are you referring to `WRKJOBSCDE`?

If so, just use option 10 'Submit immediately' to run the job.

Comment: Note that `10=Submit immediately` does not use the user profile (or job description?) specified on the scheduled job.  It uses defaults for your profile...this might cause a problem running the job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Good idea, but like @Charles mentioned, I want to avoid running into a potential problem.

Comment: David's suggest is still the best way IMHO...you just have to modify your submit to match the scheduled job.

Comment: @Charles Option 10 uses the user profile and job description, and other attributes specified in the scheduled job. You just have to be sure that is what you want as you can schedule a job to use the `*CURRENT` user and job description. There are some restrictions if the user is `QSECOFR`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  For reference sake, is there also a command line command for this?

Comment: I don't think there is a command to submit a scheduled job entry.  I would suggest you create a program to run the program (or submit the job) and have the job scheduler call that program. Then you can also manually call the same program.